# Synchronisation between CouchDB and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, couchdb

As i need to synchronise a CouchDB with a SQL Server i need your help. I'm totally new to this and I don't really know a proper way to implement this. Is it even possible without typing thousands of lines of code? If it is, what's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: There may be some useful suggestions in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730820/sql-server-and-firebase-pouchdb-synchronization/45838032#45838032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving data one way or the other in a specific case should be straight-forward. Read and parse the changes feed, convert the JSON documents to SQL statements that you then execute on the SQL Server side.

The general case (bi-directional, continuous sync between an MVCC and a non-MVCC database) is a hard problem without keeping extra state somewhere.

CouchDB has first-order support for conflicted documents, SQL Server does not. If you need your synchronisation to be bi-directional and stand up to concurrent modification of documents you will have a problem: CouchDB will quite happily accept multiple versions of the same document, a concept which has no direct equivalent on the SQL-Server side.